# Send mails with a PDF attachment without creating files on the file system

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I would like to send a PDF attachment with my emails, but without creating files on the file system.

This is what I'm trying:

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
     @profile_name='notifications_ACME',
     @recipients= 'marc.guillot@acme.com',
     @subject= 'Test PDF Attachment',
     @from_address = 'notifications@acme.com',
     @body= 'Test sending a PDF attachment',
     @query='select fileContent from documents where id = 882307',
     @query_attachment_filename = 'Test.pdf',
     @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
     @query_result_header = 0,
     @query_result_no_padding = 1
```

I'm using @query parameter to provide the binary of my PDF attachment, and trying to remove the overhead supplied by the query.

But still when I try to open the sent PDF I see something like:

```
0x255044462D312E330D0A25405044463031323334353637383920310D0A332030206F626A
0D0A3C3C0D0A20202F54797065202F584F626A6563740D0A20202F53756274797065202F49
6D6167650D0A20202F46696C746572202F4443544465636F64650D0A20202F576964746820
313234380D0A20202F4865696768742035
0x7E251E857041A9E60ED19113057EC48A861865370669822B6DDA0277FAD0013C9234EB04
2C10E3733633814D2D2DBCD1ABC9E64721DB923041A7CF03B4AB342C048A3186E84522C334
B2A3DC6C0139555F5F53400EB999A308A806F91B6AE7A0
(1 rows affected)
```

Is it possible to also remove that footer so the query only provides the binary content for the attachment? Or there is no way to provide binary attachments on the fly without persisting them on the file system? (Most of our costumers won't probably have permissions to the file system).

Thank you.

Comment: `I would like to send a PDF attachment with my emails, but without creating files on the file system.` this is the part where you should realize that perhaps you have reached the limit of dbmail and should go into a proper emailing solutions. Many programming languages support sending mails *and* attaching pdf files

Comment: Unfortunately, the footer you're seeing is a part of the default behavior of `sp_send_dbmail`. But Instead of directly attaching the binary content from a query result, you can encode the PDF binary data as `Base64` and then attach it in the email. This method bypasses the need to write the PDF to the file system and avoids the extra footer added by `sp_send_dbmail`.

Comment: you can perhaps try: `set nocount ON; select ... from somebinarytable` but it doesn't seem to actually saving the binary data, but rather binary data converted to hex presentation, which is not what you want

Comment: @codeapplied Can you post this as an answer (with a link would be lovely) and I will accept it ?.

Comment: not sure if this will work but do try

```
SELECT @PDFBase64 = CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("fileContent")))', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM documents
WHERE id = [ ];
```

Comment: You will have more luck doing this with an external process, even PowerShell with `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient`. I say this because `sp_send_dbmail` uses the legacy sqlcmd library under the covers so you're going to encounter little issues like breaks in the middle of your attachment data. You can already see one in your example data after 256 characters where it starts a second block with `0x7E...`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks, if it uses sqlcmd under the hood then it makes sense that I won't be able to use to provide a binary content.

Comment: @siggemannen You are right, the nocount only removes the footer, but the content still isn't a pdf binary but its hex representation. I'm trying the codeapplied suggestion of converting it to base64, but looks like I will definitely discard it.

Comment: @codeapplied It doesn't work, the PDF that I get still is gibberish (its seems to truncate to the first 256 characters). I will discard it definitely and we will send the mails outside the database. PS: I haven't used your base64 conversion (I get an error with the field being of image type), so I used `@query='set nocount on; select convert(varchar(max), (select convert(varbinary(max), filecontent) for XML path(''''), binary base60)) from documents WHERE id = 882142;'`